# Best Practices/Advice - Execution of jobs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to build a stream event correlation engine with Flink and I have some questions regarding the execution of jobs.

In my architecture I need to have different sources of data, lets say for instance:

```
firewallStream= environment.addSource([FirewalLogsSource]); 
proxyStream = environment.addSource([ProxyLogsSource]);
```

and for each of these sources, I need to apply a set of rules. 
So lets say I have a job that has as a source the proxy stream data with the following rules:

```
//Abnormal Request Method 
stream.[RuleLogic].addSink([output]) 
//Web Service on Non-Typical Port 
stream.[RuleLogic].addSink([output]) 
//Possible Brute Force 
stream.[RuleLogic].addSink([output])
```

These rules will probably scale to be in the order of 15 to 20 rules.

What is the best approach in this case:

1. Should I create 2 jobs one for each source and each job would have 15-20 rules?
2. Should I split the rules into several jobs?
3. Other options?

Thank you and Regards,

Pedro Chaves.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie.
I think there are 2 main concern that should take into consideration.

1. network traffic. Multiple data reader will multiple network traffic.
2. Computing Latency. Putting all logic computing into one job may increase latency.

Comment: I couldn't tell the exact answer to the question. It depends on the specific situation and system's main concern.

Comment: If we split the rules into several jobs, network traffic may be a  problem. If we put all rules in one job, computing latency may be a problem. Sorry for the ambiguous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I don't find many complete deployed implementations so it's hard to find a general rule of thumb. I did read this post https://techblog.king.com/rbea-scalable-real-time-analytics-king/. They execute all of their processes in a single job (on a fixed topology). If you know of more good examples, please let me know. Thank you.